# I am using strava login in my ios application.After authentication of strava I am not able to get back to my application

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, redirect, strava

I have used this library.
https://github.com/mpclarkson/StravaSwift

My callback url redirects me to any browser link but does not redirect me to my app.How can I redirect back to my app after authentication from strava?

Answer (score 2):

OP Mentioned usage of this GitHub cocoa pods -> https://github.com/mpclarkson/StravaSwift

using the example app within the GitHub project, the following is what is needed for redirect back to the app after Strava oAuth authentication.

info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.stravaswift.ios</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>breakaway</string> <--- This is my App Name
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Note that per the readme.md file for that project page you also need this

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>strava</string>
</array>
```

Then within appDelegate.swift (also per the readme.md)

```
  let config = StravaConfig(
        clientId: <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>,
        clientSecret: <YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>,
        redirectUri: "breakaway://breakaway701849232.wordpress.com",
    scopes: [.activityReadAll,.activityWrite]
    )
```

Edit for IOS14.5+ / Xcode 12.5+ Due to changes in ASWebuthentitor https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679251) I am getting errors with the above. The redirectUri is now changed to the below

```
  let config = StravaConfig(
        clientId: <YOUR_CLIENT_ID>,
        clientSecret: <YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>,
  redirectUri: "breakaway://breakaway701849232.wordpress.com".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!,
    scopes: [.activityReadAll,.activityWrite]
    )
```

Note that the redirectUri is "breakaway" :// "breakaway701849232.wordpress.com"
where :
breakaway - my redirectUri
breakaway701849232.wordpress.com - my domain (That is inputed into Strava API for my app)

[image]

NOTE: One Gotcha I fell into was that the Scopes is actually a comma delimited array. I kept getting errors using the example app where it lists all the activities but it was because I did not include a "ReadAll" into the scope (My goal is to upload TCX files to Strava).

Comment: With Xcode 12.5 and IOS 14.6, the redirectUri becomes an issue already. Error can be found here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/679251

Answer (score 0):

To have strava redirect back to your app, you need to register a url scheme in your info.plist file and then use that url scheme to allow the OS to recognize the redirect.

Here are some steps that should help:

1. Register url scheme in your info.plist. To do this, add a unique entry under `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in info.plist, "myApp" for example. If you do not already have `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in info.plist as an entry, you will need to create this (needs to be an array).
2. Register authorization callback domain with Strava at https://www.strava.com/settings/api, along the lines of myApp.com.
3. Assign the callbackURLScheme to match the registered url scheme in your info.plist (from step 1, "myApp"). To illustrate:

```
private var authSession: ASWebAuthenticationSession?

let appOAuthUrlStravaScheme = URL(string: "strava://oauth/mobile/authorize?client_id=1234321&redirect_uri=myApp%3A%2F%2FmyApp.com&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&scope=activity%3Awrite%2Cread&state=test")!

let webOAuthUrl = URL(string: "https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize?client_id=1234321&redirect_uri= myApp%3A%2F%2FmyApp.com&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&scope=activity%3Awrite%2Cread&state=test")!


func authenticate() {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appOAuthUrlstravaScheme) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(appOAuthUrlstravaScheme, options: [:])
    } else {
        authSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: webOAuthUrl, callbackURLScheme: "myApp") { url, error in
            // Code after redirect
        }

        authSession?.start()
    }
}
```